# Is there a way to let users directly upload image on cloudinary and store the url of the image in my mongoDB database in Node.js App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, cloudinary

I am currently storing images using multer to uploads folder in public and then to mongodb using buffer and converting back to 64bit to display it which I think its making website slow. 
I know I'm new to all this , really need a step by step procedure and explanation. Thank you

App.js->

```
const blogSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
name:String,
title:String,
image:String,
body:String,
uploadImg:{ 
    data: Buffer, 
    contentType: String 
},
created:{
    //here we define a default date in case the user doesnt type one
    type:Date,default:Date.now
}})
```

multer and storage->

```
function checkFileType(file,cb){   
//allowed extensions
//console.log(file);
const filetypes=/jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
const extname=filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
const mimetype=filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
if(mimetype && extname){
    return cb(null,true)
}else{
    //console.log(file);
    cb('Error : Only Images Accepted');
}
```

}

```
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:"./public/uploads/",
    filename:(req, file, callback)=>{
        callback(null, file.fieldname+"-"+Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname))
    },


})

var upload = multer({storage:Storage,
    limits:{fileSize:10000000},
    fileFilter:function(req,file,cb){
        checkFileType(file,cb)},      
        }
).single('file');
```

in post route->

```
 var obj = { 
                   name:req.body.name,
                    title:req.body.title,
                     image:req.body.image,
                        body:req.body.body,       
                         uploadImg: { 
                        data: fs.readFileSync(path.join( './public/uploads/' + req.file.filename)), 
                        contentType: 'image/png'} }

                        Blog.create((obj),
```

in show.ejs->

```
<img src="data:blog/<%=blog.uploadImg.contentType%>;base64,<%=blog.uploadImg.data.toString('base64')%>" alt="someImage">
```

Comment: Why do you need to show the image as base64 instead of referencing it by its URL? it shouldn't make it very slow, but it seems to be an unnecessary step

Comment: I got it , but what about my actual question, how would I upload image to cloudinary and its URL in Mongo db database in one go.  Or could there be any better option for such functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'in one go', but you can use Cloudinary's SDK to upload the image, then store the details in your database based on the response you received to the upload API call - Cloudinary's Node SDK can be found here: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm

Comment: Hey there. I believe it would be a better approach to use cloudinary npm dependency…As you’re already using node with along express and mongodb, it might be way to go… The following article explains how easy is to create a special route for a user api endpoint which handles the user profile image upload to cloudinary, including routes to update and delete the user, which will then update/delete the user’s image on cloudinary too.. https://dev.to/itsmefarhan/cloudinary-files-images-crud-operations-with-nodejs-express-multer-2147